# How can we use cordic to tanh(x+1)/tanh(x)?

Tags: math, cordic

How can we use cordic to

```
tanh(x+1)/tanh(x)
```

I can't get a idea about how to apply [cordic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) to above function.

In other word, which point on the above function, can we apply cordic?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cordic is an extremely fast and efficient algorithm for implementing trigonometric functions. The most common implementations you can find refer to sin/cos functions but it can be used for their hyperbolic counterparts.

Once you have an implementation for sinh/cosh is easy to get tanh.

Have a look [here](http://forum.mitrionics.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=100)

Comment: This link is broken.